# 404 error when running Crystal Report - when it used to work fine

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis, crystal-reports, http-status-code-404

We have an issue that has popped up revolving around running Crystal Reports Via an asp.net web page.

The system was working fine for years and then due to a hard-drive crash, had to be rebuilt.

We copied all files from a 1 day old backup onto the new system with:
Same operating system - Server 2008 R2
Same IIS - 7
Same ASP programs.
Same Crystal Reports Version 2005.
Same Web.Config
Same permissions.
Same everything!

All webpages work, 
All database functions work, 
But now, we get ...

"HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed"

... error when trying to run the pages that load a Crystal Reports report.

All asp files are there. (as well as all other files from the backup)

Only the CR reports die.

When turning off custom errors, the only thing it says is:

"HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed"

When turning on log files, all we see is "xReport.aspx ... 404"

Absolutely no useful information AT ALL is given to us by IIS about WHAT the resource or dependencies that it is looking for is.

Any clue as to what might be different or how to find out?

Answer (score 0):

Did you reinstall the Crystal Reports Runtime engine?

Comment: Haven't tried that.  We just installed it when we rebuilt the server, so it didn't cross our minds to re-install right after installing it.  However, at this point in time we are willing to try anything. Maybe something hiccuped in the installation.  We'll give it a shot.

Comment: But it was installed, correct?  I've forgotten to reinstall it more than once and been confused at the errors.  You probably don't need to reinstall it if it was already done, but definitely make sure that the version that is installed is the correct one for your application.  There are a number of redistributables and it's key to the correct one.